# In which community should I ask questions about how Cloudflare loads JavaScript files?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Cloudflare is stopping some of my AngularJs scripts from loading on my domain. To be more specific, when I test my azure site **without** Cloudflare my Angular files load, but **with** Cloudflare my Angular files fail to load.

Which community is correct for this question?

Comment: Why don't you ask CloudFlare support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) would be the best site to ask this question, if explained elaborately about the service and the problem you are facing.

In fact, [here](https://superuser.com/search?q=cloudflare) are the CloudFlare posts on SuperUser, they don't have a tag for it though!

Comment: Webmasters seems a better fit to me. And it does have the tag: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudflare